# Change row height depending on which type of tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a table view that has two custom cells. Is there any way to make these two cells have different heights?

Comment: please add question with clear what you want and if some code then good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course,

Here is apple doc [Working with Self Sizing TableViewCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html)

First of all, your cell should be  set up with constraints properly.

In second, in your View Controller you should write

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // non zero value
```

in `viewDidLoad()`

Or you can return different heights form delegate method
`func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath)`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this,

Ensure that your both cell have sufficient to be Fit in Automatic dimension.

In your class where you used `tableView` write this two lines in `viewDidLoad`.

```
//as per your table Outlet name, in my case it's tableView

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 36.0
```

Or, simply you can also defined height in `UITableView` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // Your cell Height
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this

1. From UITableView Method

   **func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
   IndexPath) -> CGFloat**
         in this method you can set height with respect to every cell 
         for 
         "indexpath.row"
2. UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   In ViewDidLoad or in other initial method write like this

   **self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44**